# Upgrading a Samsung S GT-I9000 (to anything >2.1)

Tags: 2.2-froyo, updates, samsung-galaxy-s, device-firmware

I'm new to Android, but my sister recently got a second-hand Galaxy S GT-I9000. It runs on 2.1, which means that it does not have Google Play. Apparently 2.2 does, and the device seems to be able to support that firmware.

When I try Google, it comes up with lots of people suggesting rooted firwmare upgrades to Jellybean rather than anything official. I'd rather not get into that just yet if there's an official route.

I've tried Samsung Kies, but it says the device is not supported for firmware upgrades. I've also tried checking `Settings > About > Software update`, but 'Software update' is not there.

What is the proper way to upgrade from Android 2.1 to anything higher on a Galaxy S GT-I9000? How is it *supposed to work*?

**EDIT:** I found that it should be able to officially support Gingerbread at least. Even Wikipedia mentions that as the OS.

Comment: Just a hint: If it's just about "Google Play", the corresponding app was named "Android Market" with 2.1, and still works.

Comment: I am using same set. I have upgraded to 2.3.6 using kies .. You sure that your kies are up to date? which country you are from. Some country may not have latest upgrade.

Comment: I've ended up using Odin to overwrite with 2.3.6 (and bricked my phone in the process, which I fixed later) which basically solved my problem.. I'm from the Netherlands - I didn't know that affected the update process. The device is not locked to a carrier.